# C++ How to assign string as hexadecimal

Tags: c++

I got this string

```
0x3384BCFD
0x61CEB13B
```

both are of string type..

Initially I got this

```
uint32_t iv[2]  = {0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFAA};
```

How do I assign the 2 string above into `iv[0]` and `iv[1]`?

I want the final result of `iv[2]` as `iv[2] = {0x3384BCFD,0x61CEB13B};`

**Thanks for helping!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    uint32_t iv[2];

    std::stringstream("0x3384BCFD 0x61CEB13B") >> std::hex >> iv[0] >> iv[1];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Seeing as how this isn't in the linked dupe:

```
uint32_t iv[] = { //*cough* std::array exists as well
    std::stoul(strs[0], nullptr, 16), 
    std::stoul(strs[1], nullptr, 16)
};
```

Comment: This is probably the closest to what the OP wanted, he can use this in his array declaration.

Comment: @Overv, Good point. I'll actually add that.

Answer (score 4):

Since it's C++ I suggest you to use streams with manipulators:

```
stringstream ss = stringstream("0x3384BCFD");
ss >> hex >> iv[0];
```

Comment: This is indeed a better idea.